# FFmpeg into Qt 5.0.2: exit code -1073741515 on av_register_all();

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, exit-code, libavformat

I am attempting to integrate FFmpeg into my Qt app. I used the FFmpeg git-0fb64da 64-bit Dev source from [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds page](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and added avformat.lib to my project. My .pro file:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../FFmpeg/ffmpeg-20130428-git-0fb64da-win64-dev/lib/ -lavformat

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../FFmpeg/ffmpeg-20130428-git-0fb64da-win64-dev/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../FFmpeg/ffmpeg-20130428-git-0fb64da-win64-dev/include
```

I included libavformat/avformat.h inside the "extern "C"" block.

As long as I don't call av_register_all(), this all works fine, but once I do, my app exits with code -1073741515. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2):

you have to put the necessary ffmpeg dll files beside your exe file.